# Canvas Image Turns invisible when scaled through C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to make a pokemon-like game and trying to make the healthbar out of images and scaling a green one, but when i scale it through c# it turns invisible

my code:

```
[SerializeField] GameObject health;

private void Start()
{
    health.transform.localScale = new Vector2(0.5f, 1f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you scale something, make sure you scale it properly in all 3 dimensions. `transform.localScale` is a `Vector3`, which means that if you use a `Vector2` to define it, Unity will assume that the z-component is 0. Depending on what kind of object you are scaling exactly, this can lead to very different results. For example 3D objects will disappear immediately when they dont have any scale in the z-direction, even when you only view them in the xy-system.

```
private void Start()
{
    health.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 1f, 1f);
}
```

Changing your code like this should fix the issue! If it's not that, then I don't think your disappearing game object is tied to your scaling.

I hope this helps!